# mongo db count differs from aggregate sum

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

i have a query and when i validate it i see that the count command returns a different results from the aggregate result.

i have an array of sub-documents like so:

```
{
    ...
    wished: [{'game':'dayz','appid':'1234'}, {'game':'half-life','appid':'1234'}]
    ...
}
```

i am trying to query a count of all games in the collection and return the name along with the count of how many times i found that game name.

if i go

```
db.user_info.count({'wished.game':'dayz'})
```

it returns 106 as the value and

```
db.user_info.aggregate([{'$unwind':'$wished'},{'$group':{'_id':'$wished.game','total':{'$sum':1}}},{'$sort':{'total':-1}}])
```

returns 110

i don't understand why my counts are different.  the only thing i can think of is that it has to do with the data being in an array of sub-documents as opposed to being in an array or just in a document.

Comment: Is it possible a user can wish for the same game twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $unwind statement will cause one user with multiple wished games to appear as several users. Imagine this data:

```
{ 
 _id: 1,
 wished: [{game:'a'}, {game:'b'}]
}
{
 _id: 2,
 wished: [{game:'a'}, {game:'c'}, {game:'a'}]
}
```

The `count` can NEVER be more than 2.

But with this same data, an `$unwind` will give you 5 different documents. Summing them up will then give you a:3, b:1, c:1.